# SystemStackError in HomeController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

You can see the error here:
http://www.petralian.com/ffcrm/

I try to install fatfree crm and this is the error it throws. I cannot find any solution to it.

```
SystemStackError in HomeController#index

stack level too deep

Rails.root: /webapps/ffcrm
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409
```

Comment: Could it be a debugger causing this?  Also, add some debugging statements to determine which line this is happening at and post it please.

Comment: what version of fatfree crm are you installing ?

Comment: I am installing fat free crm v0.11.3-122.

Comment: I am not sure how to add debugging statements and where to do this... I managed to install RoR on my server and get this far by reading countless tutorials and trying countless things.

Comment: I fixed it for a while with increasing ulimit -s 32768 but now it stopped working again. I really have no clue what causes this error and how to fix it.

Comment: I have reinstaled everything I could but the same error came up... this is really strange.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up removing Ruby 1.9.3, upgrading my server from CentOS 5.8 to 6.3 and reinstalling Ruby 1.9.2 from rvm. Now it works!